# Glitch drawing on JComponent

Tags: java, swing, drawing

I'm having this weird kind of glitch with drawing on an JComponent.
What happens is that whenever i drag the JFrame window outside the bounds of my monitor, the drawing accelerates and draws faster than it should. I'm guessing it has to do something with swing management, seems like drawing stops once the Jframe is offscreen and resumes in a burst kind of way after being set inside the bounds of the monitor screen.

Here's my code:

```
package javagame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

/**
*
* 
*/
public class Screen extends JComponent implements Runnable{

// paintbrush for drawing.
//private Graphics internalg;
private boolean keepDrawing = true;
public Screen() {        
   super();
   startDrawing();
}

/// Draw methods
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {         
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //internalg = g;
    //Draw 
    //System.out.println("painted");
    drawSomething(g);
}   

@Override
public void run() {
    //Draw until manually stopped
    while(keepDrawing){
        repaint();
    try { Thread.sleep(100); }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
    }
}
/**
 * Fire off thread.
 */
private void startDrawing()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    //thread ends when JFrame is closed.
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();

}
/// Draw Logic ///


/// Images
int d = 2;
public void drawSomething( Graphics internalg )
{
    if (isValid()){   
        internalg.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        internalg.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());//clear bg
        internalg.setFont( new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 15) );
        internalg.setColor( Color.GREEN );
        internalg.drawOval( (getWidth()/2)-(d/2) , (getHeight()/2)-(d/25), d, d);
        d++;
    }
}

/// Images

}
```

Comment: I, personally, would avoid the use of `Thread`s to perform animation (unless you have a particularly complex model that might take a variable amount of time to update) and rely on `javax.swing.Timer` instead

Comment: Ditto on @MadProgrammer's advice. Also you shouldn't have any program logic within your drawing code, even something as seemingly innocuous as `d++`. You do not have full control over when or if drawing will take place.

Comment: I'm not seeing your particular issue under Java 7/Windows 7.  It is possible that you might getter a better refresh under some circumstances as the required area to be updated is smaller, but I don't see it...

Comment: hmm ill upload a youtube video to show you guys whats going on.

Comment: Using threads is a requirement for this little project, but thanks for the tip. Here's a video of the glitch : http://youtu.be/2XAgU5L9DnQ The Circle grows too fast when its dragged off screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't have program logic in your painting methods.
- Use floating point numbers, double, to do your scaling, not an int, like d.
- Base the value of your scaling number on the System time, not on logic contained within code you have no control over how fast it is called, the painting methods.